# Unity animation shows it is being played, while it isn't played at all

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have my main character. It has animator attached to it. Animator on it's own has boolean variable "IsWalking" which is true only while button W is down. However, I got new animations from my designer. The animations were made in Mixamo, using the body of the main character. When I added them in unity and made the transition "ifs" a problem occurred. My main character animator loads the animation as if it is being played, yet, nothing happens to the character he stays paralysed on place. Any ideas? I tried "apply rood motion", it didn't help.

Comment: Sounds like the animation was made for a different model and the bones aren't set up properly any more.

Comment: But my designer said he used the model, that i have, in mixamo, could it still be this reason?

Comment: No idea, I am not a 3D artist/animator. Nor have I ever heard of Mixamo.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway